# Regex: need some help match using semicolon

Tags: regex

I have the following input: `Mobileapp/1.19.2 (SM-S908B; Android 12; da-DK)`

I either need to match `(SM-S908B;` and `da-DK)` or just `(SM-S908B;`

So match anything between `(` and first `;` and last `;` and `)`

I tried and and was able to use this expression `([^(;]+);([^;]+)`
But it matches to SM-S908B; Android 12

Would really appreciate if anyone could help since I am still learning Regex.

Comment: Which regex variant are you using?

Comment: Are these values always between parenthesis? What do you mean by: "or just `(SM-S908B;`" Do you want to match including the opening parenthesis `(SM-S908B;` or only the content in between stopping before the first semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming at least one occurence of the semi-colon is present, maybe chuck both options in their own group:

```
(?:\(([^;]+)|;\s*([^;)]+)\))
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ep41R/1)

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group;

  - `\(([^;]+)` - Match a literal open-paranthesis followed by a 1st capture group to match 1+ non-semicolon characters;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `;\s*([^;)]+)\)` - Match a semicolon and 0+ whitespace characters before a 2nd capture group to match 1+ characters other than semicolon or closing paranthesis.

---

Another option is to match just these parts:

```
(?:\(|;.*;\s*|\G(?!^))\K[^;)]+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Am7MBD/1)

- `(?:` - Open non-capture group;

  - `\(` - Match an open paranthesis;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `;.*;\s*` - Match from 1st semicolon to last semicolon with possible 0+ whitespace chars;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `\G(?!^)` - Assert position at end of previous match but exclude start-line with negative lookahead;
- `\K` - Reset starting point of reported match;
- `[^;)]+` - Match 1+ characters other than semicolon or closing paranthesis.